# multiple OR in IF statement in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Am trying to validate multiple statements in Coffeescript before I continue.

I have something basic like this:

```
 if ext != 'jpeg' || ext != 'pdf' || ext != 'jpg'

     alert('extension must be jpg, pdf, jpeg')
```

What am I doing wrong here? am new to Coffee and thought something as basic as this shouldn't be hard to do.

Comment: should be `and` (`&&`) not `or` (`||`)

Comment: `(ext != 'jpeg' || ext != 'pdf' || ext != 'jpg') == (true)`. What you are saying is that it can be anything apart from `'jpeg'`, **or** anything apart from `'pdf'`... If you think about that, that means that it can be `'jpeg'` or `'pdf'` or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `&&`.

```
if ext != 'jpeg' && ext != 'pdf' && ext != 'jpg'
     alert('extension must be jpg, pdf, jpeg')
```

Comment: Sorry I did initially write it in Javascript! You were right, I have now corrected the code for CoffeeScript

Answer (score 7):

CoffeeScript has an [`in` operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) so you can say `element in array` to make the logic more compact:

> You can use `in` to test for array presence, [...]

In your case:

```
if ext !in ['jpeg', 'pdf', 'jpg']
    alert('extension must be jpg, pdf, jpeg')
```

The current CoffeeScript compiler is smart enough to recognize that pattern and produces this JavaScript:

```
if (ext !== 'jpeg' && ext !== 'pdf' && ext !== 'jpg') {
  alert('extension must be jpg, pdf, jpeg');
}
```

rather than something more expensive.

Comment: Nice to know. Would this work even though I don't have an array? I would hate to build an array only to loop through it and validate the values. Seems like a bit of extra code

Comment: The array only exists in the CoffeeScript version, an array literal will be expanded inline when it is converted to JavaScript. `e in [a,b,c]` is just just a shorter way of saying `e === a || e === b || e === c`.